# Combination Question (Red and Blue team)

Tags: combinatorics

Problem: Some students in a gym class are wearing blue jerseys, and the rest are wearing red jerseys. There are exactly 25 ways to pick a team of three players that includes at least one player wearing each color. Compute the number of students in the class.

My failed solution: When I tried to do this question, I defined $r$ as being the number of players on the red team, and $b$ as being the number players on the blue team. Thus the total number of ways to pick a team of three would be $((b)(r)(b+r-2))/(3!)=25$. This does not lead to a solution for $b$ or $r$ (using prime factorization). What did I do wrong?

Comment: @whoever down voted this post, can you please state how I can improve my question? Thank you!

Comment: The number of ways of selecting a team would be $\binom{b}{2}\binom{r}{1}+\binom{b}{1}\binom{r}{2}$.  You seem to have ignored in your calculations that the order of students on the team does not matter and further even if it did matter, you could have the same color twice in a row and the different color last

Comment: But each guy is different, right?

Comment: Yes.  And?  Where in my solution does it sound like the guys aren't different?  Note further that your proposed solution yields results that aren't even integers for several cases, for example if there are three people: one wearing a blue shirt and two wearing red., your solution would have it sound like there are $\frac{1}{3}$ ways to choose the team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's okay to say pick a blue guy, then a red guy, then anybody who's left.  The only mistake is in how you adjusted for double counting.  You've only counted each team twice, not six times.  Say Alex and Bob are blue and Charlie is red.  In you scheme, you count Alex, Charlie, Bob and Bob, Charlie, Alex, but no other permutation.

You should have gotten $$br(b+r-2)=50$$